# How to automate creation of map layers and export images with arcpy

Tags: python, arcgis, arcpy

I have point data (observer points) and for each point I need a map (that can be printed) with the point at the center and multiple ringbuffers with increasing distance (100m, 300m, 500m, 1000m) around it. Additionally I need the point to be labeled with an ID and a scale bar.

So far I have managed to import a .csv file save it as a FC and create the buffers around the points using arcpy but cant figure out how to create images and export the layouts, one for each point. I am working in the python window in arcgis pro. I see that there is an arcpy.mapping module for arc gis desktop which has a `.ExportToJPEG` function but can't find that in the pro version.

I am a total newb to arcpy and quite new to python in general and would appreciate if somebody could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

The module for pro is arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject.  The documentation for it starts here:
https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/arcpy/mapping/introduction-to-arcpy-mp.htm

```
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(r'path\to\the\arcgis\aprxfile.aprx')
aprxLayout = aprx.listLayouts()[0] '''adding the zero index will return the first 
    layout in the layout list, of there is more than one layout in the ArcGIS 
    project'''
aprxLayout.exportToPDF(r'path\to\folder\FileName.pdf')
```

arcpy.cartography.StripMapIndexFeatures can be used to update the map series in the aprx, that exports a pdf that contains a page for each point.
https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/tool-reference/cartography/strip-map-index-features.htm

First a line will have to be created from the points to use with the arcpy.cartography.StripMapIndexFeatures tool

```
#use feature class list to get the fc you want
pntFcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(feature_type='Point')
fieldNames = ['field','SHAPE']
for pointFc in pntFcList:
    insertCursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(pointFc, fieldNames)
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(pointFc, fieldNames, control) as sc:
        for row in sc:
            point = row[]
            newX = point[0]
            newY = point[1] + 1
            newPoint = (newX, newY)
            t = row
            newRow = list(t)
            newRow[1] = newPoint
            t = tuple(newRow)
    insertCursor.insertRow(t)
    del insertCursor
lineFcName = 'LineFc'
lineFc = r'path\to.gdb\fCName'
arcpy.PointsToLine_management(pointFc,lineFc)
```

Then the line feature class can be used as input to create the index features for the map series

```
# creates the index feature for the map series
arcpy.cartography.StripMapIndexFeatures(lineFc, outIndexFc, "NO_USEPAGEUNIT", None, "" + str(length) + " Feet", "" + str(width) + " Feet", "HORIZONTAL",5,                                                    1, "WE_NS")

# refresh the map series in the aprx
if not aprxLayout.mapSeries is None:
    ms = aprxLayout.mapSeries
    if ms.enabled:
        ms = aprxLayout.mapSeries
        ms.refresh()
ms.exportToPDF(r'output\path\filename.pdf','ALL)
```